# Intent filter matches when I test, but not when I follow a link

Tags: android, android-intent

I've looked at so many "this is how you do intents" questions that I've got to be missing something obvious.

I have a program which is supposed to watch for and intercept a specific link as you are browsing.  When I generate a test intent and check the resolution using queryIntentActivities, it matches.  However, when I browse to a page with this link and tap it, the browser happily goes on to follow that link rather than giving the expected popup.

Code to test the intent:

```
private Intent makeTestIntent() {
    Intent testIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://my.machine.com/WebAppName/connect.link"));
    testIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_DEBUG_LOG_RESOLUTION);
    return testIntent;
}
public boolean testHomeIntent() {
    Intent testIntent = makeTestIntent();
    List<ResolveInfo> resolution = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(testIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
// I test by adding a breakpoint here and looking at the resolution list.  The return value is irrelevant.
    return true;
}
```

When I run this, the resolution list has three entries: my activity, the stock browser, and Firefox, all at priority 0 with isDefault false.  As I said, though, when I go to a web page with the same link, my activity does not come up.  It just keeps browsing.

Relevant portions of the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.my.package.name"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >


<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" 
              android:normalScreens="true"
              android:largeScreens="true"
              android:anyDensity="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_label" >
    ... other activities removed for brevity
    <activity
        android:name="com.my.package.name.ConnectActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:label="@string/set_link_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="http"
                  android:host="my.machine.name"
                  android:path="/WebAppName/connect.link" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />   
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> 
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Hopefully I haven't introduced too many typos in taking out application-name-specific parts.  I've also checked that none of the applications are already set to get this intent by default.  That should show up in the test resolver anyway, right?

Note that I am not using webview here - I want the user to be able to have their own browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer turns out to be "Uninstall Firefox."  Or at least stop using it.

At this time, Firefox will remain in the browser rather than giving other options.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=653833 - it's marked fixed, but look at comments 36 and 37.

When I switched from Firefox back to the native browser it behaved as I expected.